# Java Processing Projectile Motion

Tags: java, processing, angle

I am trying to create a angry-birds like game for my homework but i am having trouble with angle and projectile motion. I give it gravity*time module but it doesnt seem to be going in projectile motion what could be the problem ?

```
float gravity = 9.75;
float time = 0;
float speedx=20;
float speedy=440;

int speed = 0;
int angle = 0;

String veloc = "";



void setup(){
size(800,600);
}


 void keyPressed() {
  if( key >= '0' && key <= '9' ){
    veloc+=char(key);
    if( abs( int( veloc ) ) > 1000 ){
        speed = int(veloc.substring(0,2));  
        angle = int(veloc.substring(2,4));
        println("Speed is " + speed + " m/sec");
        println("Angle is " + angle + " degree");
        time = time + 1;
    }
  } 
}





void draw() {



  background(129,201,255);
  strokeWeight(0);
fill(64,152,3);
rect(0,200,800,600);

fill(188,133,61);
rect(400,375,150,30);
rect(400,500,150,30);
rect(400,275,150,30);



rect(400,400,30,120);
rect(520,400,30,120);
rect(400,275,30,120);
rect(520,275,30,120);

PImage slingshot;
slingshot = loadImage("slingshot.png");
image(slingshot, 30, 450);


PImage pig;
pig = loadImage("pig.png");
image(pig, 460, 253);
image(pig, 410, 253);
image(pig, 510, 253);
image(pig, 435, 353);
image(pig, 485, 353);
image(pig, 435, 478);
image(pig, 485, 478);

text("Please Type a Magnitude (0-99) and an Angle (0-99). E.g. 1045 , Speed = 10, Angle = 45", 120, 30);



  PImage bird;
  bird = loadImage("bird.png");
  image(bird, speedx, speedy);

  speedx = speedx + (speed * cos(angle));
  speedy = speedy + (speed * -sin(angle)) + gravity*time;

}
```

Comment: you don't list a problem clearly; that is the problem with your question.

Comment: here are some pointers... unless you want wind resistance, the horizontal speed is constant. you only need to really worry about the proper vertical distance calculation - which will be 'acceleration due to gravity' like in your physics book - minus the initial velocity.

Comment: I agree with Randy. Treat your velocity as two parts (combine them if you need them combined; take arctan(verticalVelocity/horizontalVelocity) for the angle). Let the horizontal velocity be constant and have the vertical velocity be affected by gravity. Something like this: `double vVelocity = 30;\, hVelocity = 2, gravAccel = 9.8; // obviously let them be whatever you want` then in your update velocity method: `vVelocity -= gravAccel*updateTime/1000; // assumes updateTime is in millisecs, you can forget that also, its up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not expressly stating what the problem is that you want to solve, so I'm going to recommend you just look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile which lists pretty much the total sum knowledge on how ballistic trajectories work (including those that apply to Angry Bird ordnance) and just implement those functions. They're pretty easy, and almost self-explanatory.